# Mythtv what is causing empty (0 kb) recordings

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv, dvb-t

Does anyone have the same problem or an answer to what is causing empty recordings in mythtv? It also freezes up the backend when it occurs and a reboot seems to be the only thing to help. This problem occurs randomly during recordings.

I have 3 pci DVB-T cards:
2 * TerraTec Cinergy 1200 DVB-T and
1 * Satelco Easywatch PCI DVB-T

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 DVB cards and I was seeing zero byte recordings (no system freeze though).  I fixed it by adding the

```
vmalloc=192M
```

kernel parameter to the grub command line that boots the system.  See [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/mythtv/users/226072)

for some discussion on it.